# How do i load my React component conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, components

How do i load my React toolbar component conditionally on state change?

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentpagenum: 0,
        };
    }

render(){
   return(
       <View>
           {this.state.currentpagenum!==0 ? this.getToolbar(): null;}
       </View>
    );
}

getToolbar(){
      return(
            <ToolbarAndroid />
      );
 }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: remove semicolon at the end after null

Comment: thanks that was it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you got a typo error you added `;` after `null` this is unneeded also you can get rid of the `getToolbar function` Instead try:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      currentpagenum: 0,
  };
}

render() {
  return(
      <View>
          {this.state.currentpagenum !== 0 ? <ToolbarAndroid /> : null}
      </View>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to render something conditionally is to do this:

```
render() {
  return(
      <View>
          {this.state.currentpagenum !== 0 && <ToolbarAndroid />}
      </View>
   );
}
```

Which of course due to how 'truthiness' works in javascript, means you could shorten that further to this:

```
render() {
  return(
      <View>
          {this.state.currentpagenum && <ToolbarAndroid />}
      </View>
   );
}
```