# Conditionally rendered map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This code without any conditions works okay:

```
return (

    <div id="home" className="container">

        <p>Current session: {session}</p>

        { Object.keys(cart).map( (thing, i) => 
        <p key={i}>{ JSON.stringify(cart[thing]) }</p>

        ) }

    </div>

)
```

If I add this type of condition it works (without the map function):

```
return (
    <div id="home" className="container">

       { session &&
           <p>Current session: {session}</p>
        } 

      </div>       
)
```

But if I try to add that map function from the first example, it doesn't work:

```
  return ( 

    <div id="home" className="container"> 

       { session &&

        <p>Current session: {session}</p>

        { Object.keys(cart).map( (thing, i) => 
            <p key={i}>{ JSON.stringify(cart[thing]) }</p>

         )} 
       } 

   </div>

 )
```

How could I add a map function that only rendered in a condition? I tried a ternary condition and there seemed to be a similar problem with that as well. What adjustment do I need to make?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean specifically? What doesn't work? Is it simply a problem of not having a root node? In your first example you have a single outer div to contain the whole return value...

Comment: First of all, your second snippet would be interpreted as an object being returned because of `({ … })`. Second of all, assuming you're in React 16+, you'd need to wrap multiple children in an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i load my React component conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615767/how-do-i-load-my-react-component-conditionally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the returned component in a div.  This will require two divs in your case, to handle the possibility of `session` being undefined. The ternary variation you tried would have had the same issue.

```
return (
  <div>
    { session && 

        <div>
        <p>Current session {session}</p>

        {
          Object.keys(cart).map( (thing,i) => {
            <p key={i}>{ JSON.stringify(cart[thing]) }</p>
          })
        }
        </div>

    }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I forgot to add the outer div to two of my examples. But that other div you added solved the problem! I didn't know that this was required.

Answer (score 2):

basically the second argument after the condition needs to wrapped either in a `div` or as an array if you are using React v16.1 or lower

like

```
return (
  <div>
    { session && 

        [
            <p>Current session {session}</p>,
             Object.keys(cart).map( (thing,i) => {
                <p key={i}>{ JSON.stringify(cart[thing]) }</p>
              })
         ]

    }
  </div>
);
```

**[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxxlm0z433)**

or else if using v16.2, you can make use of Fragment

```
return (
  <div>
    { session && 

        <React.Fragment>
        <p>Current session {session}</p>

        {
          Object.keys(cart).map( (thing,i) => {
            <p key={i}>{ JSON.stringify(cart[thing]) }</p>
          })
        }
        </React.Fragment>

    }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I use React 15.6.2, I tried your idea using an array but got error "unexpected token" indicating the dot at Object.keys. You can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k1o6lyyy7o (look at Home component)

Comment: That is because inside an array, you need not wrap statements with `{}`